# Flutter Navigation bar inside stateless widget

Tags: flutter, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement bottomNavigationBar on the screen, which is initially extends Stateless widget.
Because of that I obviously cannot use

```
     onDestinationSelected: (index) => setState(() => this.index = index),
```

because "The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'LevelSelectionScreen'" since it is stateless.

I declared my stateful class before stateless this way:

```
    class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
    }

    class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
    int index = 0;
    final pages = [
    MainMenuScreen(),
    AvailabilityScreen(),
    SettingsScreen(),
    ];
    }
```

But in this case missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'.

Could you please help me with pointing out to the right sequence of stateful and stateless widget as I only could find the navigation bar with stateful class implementation.

Thank you!

Here is the code for the whole navigation bar

```
    class LevelSelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    const LevelSelectionScreen({super.key});
    static const _gap = SizedBox(height: 30);


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final playerProgress = context.watch<PlayerProgress>();
    final onTap;
    bool isButtonPressed = false;
    int index = 0;
    return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
      height: 60,
      selectedIndex: index,
      onDestinationSelected: (index) => setState(() => this.index = 
      index),
      destinations: [
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'home',

      ),
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.book),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
        label: 'learn',
      ),
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.gamepad),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.gamepad),
        label: 'play',
      ),
       NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: 'profile',
      ),
      ]),
```

Comment: If you're not able to use stateful widget, you must use State management solution such as provider, bloc, riverpod etc. If you want I can give you an example with provider.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting stateless widget into stateful:

```
class LevelSelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    const LevelSelectionScreen({super.key});
    @override
    _LevelSelectionScreenState createState() => 
    _LevelSelectionScreenState();
}

class _LevelSelectionScreenState extends 
    State<LevelSelectionScreen> {
        int index = 0;
        void _onDestinationSelected(int index) {
            setState(() {
                this.index = index;
            });
        }
```